# Is is possible to use HTTPS/SSL in an Ionic2/Angular2 application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic2

I have been looking for an example on how to use **SSL/https** in an Ionic2/Angular2 Cordova mobile application, but have not been able to find one.

Is there a recommended way to do this? I have been looking in `{ Http } from '@angular/http'` but can't see anything obvious exposed.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Angular2 it can be a little misleading when you see the Http object, it leads you to think that there should be an Https object, which there is not. To use https with the Http object, you simply specify that in the URL string argument for any of the methods [get(URL), post(URL,body)...]. For example

```
export class Example{
  private _dataFromGet: {};
  constructor(private _http:Http){
    this._dataFromGet = {};
  }

  retrieveData():void{
    _http.get("https://SomeUrlHere")
         .map(res:Response => res.json())
         .subscribe(data => {
           this._dataFromGet = data;
         });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah that's all there is to it. Great thankyou very much for that.